# Multisim : Wrong Output for 1 way traffic light using 555 timers

Tags: led, capacitor, diodes, 555, multisim

I made a curcuit using the given diagram in Multisim but my output is of the order Green->Yellow->Green->(Yellow and Red) . Pls tell what should I do to get the output of the order Green->Yellow->Red
The link of the circuit is https://www.multisim.com/content/bXVdiYwFbtRPj7UKASFCaj/traffic-lights/ and the circuit diagram is :[image]

Comment: do not use the output of one part of the circuit to power another part of the circuit ... both parts of the circuit should be powered at all times ... use the output of one part to enable/disable the other part

Comment: So does it mean the circuit diagram is wrong or the circuit which I made in Multisim ? Most probably the circuit diagram is correct but my circuit in Multisim is wrong .